# Help with the Rifle the Bodies quest

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In the Rifle the Bodies quest in Dragon Blight, I am supposed to find the moon rest gardens plans by looking for clues by rifling the corpse of the highborn.  When I kill them, they turn into little black balls.

How do I rifle them?

Comment: Look for the ones that are already dead.

Answer (score 4):

It's in the loot of the dead guys. Just find enough of them. You don't have to kill the *Dragonblight Mage Hunter*s (Ok, it's easier to kill them in order to loot the other corpses, but they don't drop that quest item).

You'll find bags in the loot and if you open them (right click) you get either grey trash or that quest item.

Look for these:
[image]

Image source (and more info): [Wowhead](http://www.wowhead.com/quest=11999/rifle-the-bodies#screenshots)

Comment: Sorry, still can't do it, I killed many of them, can I get the plan without killing them?  it says in the quest"Rifle their corpses for clues" so I am assuming I have to kill them first.

Comment: Now I get it, I am supposed to right click on the bag I pick up from the body to find the plan, thanks.

Comment: @Nonos You don't have to kill them. They're already dead. Those bodies are spread all around the area. Sorry for not mentioning to open the bags. I thought that was clear enough when I said the item is given by one.